# Read a parameterized SQL query from a lookup file

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement wherein I have a bunch of files containing sql queries as below. I am reading the content of the file i.e. the sql query in a look up activity in a for loop. I then pass the query to the copy activity and load the target table. Also, I am getting the PreviousFiscalYear from another lookup a activity called 'lkp-get-param-list' in the same pipeline.

```
select * from rpt.SomeTable where SubFiscalYear = '@{activity('lkp-get-param-list').output.firstRow.PreviousFiscalYear}'
```

If I pass the below query as is to the copy activity the job completes without any issues. But as soon as I try to pass it via a lookup activity is fails. Also the job completes without any issues if I hardcode the parameter as below in the file and read it via lookup activity and pass it on to copy activity.

```
select * from rpt.SomeTable where SubFiscalYear = 2019
```

Do I need to code the parameters in some other way in the .sql config file. Any pointers would be helpful.

Edit1: This is how a sample query is passed from Lookup activity to copy activity(The actual query is much more complicated has bunch of joins and filter criteria):

```
{
    "source": {
        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
        "sqlReaderQuery": "select \r\n    D_OrganizationID,\r\n    OrgName,\r\nFROM\r\n    rpt.D_Organization b b.SubFiscalYear = '@{activity('lkp-get-param-list').output.firstRow.PreviousFiscalYear}'\r\n",
        "queryTimeout": "00:10:00",
        "isolationLevel": "ReadCommitted",
        "partitionOption": "None"
    },
    "sink": {
        "type": "AzureSqlSink"
    },
    "enableStaging": false,
    "translator": {
        "type": "TabularTranslator",
        "typeConversion": true,
        "typeConversionSettings": {
            "allowDataTruncation": true,
            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error message? some screenshots would also help

Comment: This is the error message in the copy activity: Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Incorrect syntax near 'lkp'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Incorrect syntax near 'lkp'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=102,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=102,State=1,Message=Incorrect syntax near 'lkp'.,},],'

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `Lookup` activity output by adding the SQL query dynamically in `Copy Data` activity source.

Use the **CONCAT** function to include lookup activity output in the query.

**Query**:

```
@concat('select * from sampletable where subfiscalyear = ', string(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.fiscalyear))
```

[image]

Code:

```
 "source": {
                    "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                    "sqlReaderQuery": {
                        "value": "@concat('select * from sampletable where subfiscalyear = ', string(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.fiscalyear))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                    "partitionOption": "None"
                },
```